# layout method in my controller not called rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am upgrade from rails 2 to rails3 and in my controller code is like this

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  layout :choose_layout

  def choose_layout
   return 'login' if action_name == 'login' or action_name == 'set_new_password'
   return 'forgotpw' if action_name == 'forgot_password'
   return 'dashboard' if action_name == 'dashboard'
   'application'
  end

  def all
    @users = User.active.all
  end
end
```

the above layout method is working fine on rails2 but it is not call in rails3. I don't know why it is happen and if i am write code like this in action

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def all
    @users = User.active.all
    render :layout => choose_layout
  end

  def choose_layout
   layout_name ="application"
   layout_name = 'login' if action_name == 'login' or action_name == 'set_new_password'
   layout_name = 'forgotpw' if action_name == 'forgot_password'
   layout_name = 'dashboard' if action_name == 'dashboard'
   layout_name
  end
end
```

Then layout render perfectly.

can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: Do you set a layout at `ApplicationController`? if so, try set it off to test if it causes the issue?

Comment: hi Thanks for help it is not working i am write it on app controller

Comment: I meant check your `application_controller` code, does it has like a default layout there `layout :somthing`? check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout last comments mentions a conflict in that case!

Comment: Hi there is not have any method
I try to add a method `layout :method_name` but it is not call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it is happen but when i debug the controller self object and check there is any layout name like this

```
self.action_has_layout?
```

then it will produce me `nil`  so I am add a before filter on application controller and check if there is layout is nil then I am set layout by using `self.action_has_layout =` method.
and it was working fine for me.

for example my code is now something like this

```
before_filter :set_default_layout
def set_default_layout
    unless self.action_has_layout?
      self.action_has_layout = "application"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## Method #1

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  layout :choose_layout

  def choose_layout
   case action_name
   when 'login', 'set_new_password'
     'login'
   when 'forgot_password'
     'forgotpw'
   when 'dashboard'
     'dashcboard'
   else
     'application'
   end
  end
end
```

## Method #2

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  layout "application"
  layout "login", only: [:login, :set_new_password]
  layout "forgotpw", only: [:forgot_password]
  layout "dashboard", only: [:dashboard]
end
```

Comment: I got this error 

`undefined method `layout' for #<UserController:0xb533f65c>`

Comment: I've tested both on rails 3, and they actually do work. Just keep `layout "application"` on top if you are going for Method #2

Comment: Not working I am also do this in app controller `include AbstractController::Layouts::ClassMethods` Is there is anything i am missing
i am using rails 3.2.14 and ruby ruby-1.9.3-p547